# browser is getting hang on loading of markers on google map

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using asp.net/C# for a web page. I used Google map api for showing geo map in my website.
I am showing markers with different colour on basis of filter condition like in attached image. If I use one filter at a time then markers are appearing very nicely but if use multiple filter or "All" filter then browser stuck and it gives page load error.

[image: Filtered Geo Map]

Here is error page after selecting multiple option or "All" option in filter

[image: Error Page with multiple filter for markers]

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin it is giving page unresponsive,i am attaching image for that error.